# Extremely bad battery time on Ubuntu 19.04 (even with TLP and powertop)

Tags: battery

I've just bought a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 19.04 on it. According to the seller the laptop should have a battery life of about 9 hours, however I've only been able to get about 1,5 hours. I have installed TLP and powertop and used these on automatic configuration to try to get the battery life up, but no more than 3 hours sadly.

The laptop is a Lenovo L340-15IRH by the way.

I'd greatly appreciate any help, and if I need to provide more info, just say so